# Regular expression for context free grammar

Tags: regex

I have this context free grammar :
S -> aSb

S -> aSa

S -> bSa

S -> bSb

S -> epsilon 
I want to show that this grammar describes a regular language ( namely can be represented as a regular expression) but I'm not sure how to do that and get the confident I'm not missing any pattern.
I did not see this exact question and that why I don't think it is duplicate. I'd like an explanation on this relative simple example. It was hard for me to follow more complicated examples.

Answer (score -1):

You must build a DFA or regular expression. The DFA will have 2 states in this case, I think. q1(even) move to q2(odd) after a, b and from q2 move to q1 after a, b. The start and accepting state is q1.

[image: Here you have. I think DFA look like]

Comment: I believe so.My thinking is  that  it is  all strings with even length ( and that regular) but I can't prove it.

Comment: Hi, @PoliteMan, your question is better suited as a comment on the question rather than an answer. To qualify as an answer, it should provide some meaningful information in regards to the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: @ Maya2  I think so. You must build a DFA or regular expression. DFA will have 2 states in this case, I think.
q1(even) move to q2(odd) after a, b and from q2 move to q1 after a, b. The start and accepting state is q1.

Comment: My question is how to convert this BNF into a regular expression, without guessing that it corresponds to an even length string